# Call method / trigger an action on a child component in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

I am trying to utilise `component` in Angular 1.6 with:

- one-way data binding for inputs (e.g. `< bindings` instead of `=`)
- events for outputs (`& bindings`).

What is the best approach for calling functions in the child component from the parent component?

In my scenario, my child component will represent a modal dialog with a `showModal()` function. I want to pass in an ID for the item I want to edit (easy enough with a `<` input binding) and then call the child component's `showModal()` method from the parent component (item list).

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The child component knows when the ID is passed so it can call `showModal()` itself.

Comment: As you say, I can tell when an item is selected in the parent by using the child component's $onChanges hook (the id passed down will change). But that's not the point at which I want to trigger `showModal()`. The user should select an item in the parent list, then they press a button which tells the child component to show the modal if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an additional binding to control the visibility of the dialog:.

```
'visible': '<'

$onChanges(changes) {
  if(changes.visible && changes.visible.currentValue) {
   this.showDialog();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey May be you know already but let me point one more most common thing which is  broadcasting event from parent to child this works best.

if you know broadcasting events with data  like this

```
  $rootScope.$broadcast('resetDataRange',{id:1});
```

this you should write into your parent component when you want to call method of the child

In Child

```
      $rootScope.$on("resetIntraDataRange",function(data){

showModal(data.id); 

                });
```

this will call when broadcasting event triggered and you will get what you want into child .

100%  working solution